# Processingでリアルタイムに滑らかにぼかしをかける方法について

Tags: processing

iPhoneX以降のモデルのロック解除時やコントロールセンターを呼び出す際、指のスライド具合で画面の特定部分にぼかしがかかりますが、Processingで同じような表現をしたくてfilter(BLUR, 5.0*mouseX/width)などと関数を使っても、ぼかし具合が強くなると処理が重くなってしまいます。これを滑らかに行う方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: `mouseX` を使っているということは、リアルタイムに処理がしたくて、だから処理の遅さが気になっているということであっていますでしょうか？　Processing だと gif アニメとして出力することもありますが、そうではなくてインタラクティブに操作するアプリを作ろうとなさっているのですよね。

Comment: そうです！すみません、リアルタイムの処理であることを書き忘れていました。普通の処理速度を保ちつつぼかし具合がリアルタイムに変えられるようなプログラムが書きたいのです...